# How to enable Jupyter Notebook extensions in Bluemix?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook

Trying to launch the ipyleaflet inside IBM's Bluemix notebooks (now Data Science Experience) as described in [here](http://jupyter.org/widgets.html#ipyleaflet).

I'm able to install the ipyleaflet fine, using `!pip` but when I try to enable the JS extension of the widget I'm facing a permission denied error because access to the Jupyter config files is prohibited.

I tried:

```
!jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet
```

And even tried:

```
import notebook.nbextensions
notebook.nbextensions.install_nbextension('https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js', user=True)
E = notebook.nbextensions.EnableNBExtensionApp()
E.toggle_nbextension_python('ipyleaflet')
```

But they all end up similarly with a long stack that ends in:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/src/bluemix_jupyter_bundle.v25/provision/jupyter-ax-ext/nbconfig'
```

or:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/src/bluemix_jupyter_bundle.v25/notebook/etc'
In [1]:
```

pending on the specific parameters (with or without `sys-prefix`)

I found lots of explanations how to bypass that but they all require that you either have access to the system and/or the Jupyter installation.

Any ideas how this can be done with merely the notebook user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `widgetsnbextension` is not enabled per default for the Jupyter installation. As you mentioned, for all possible workarounds you would need access to the system, which users do not have.

The best way to get the option enabled, it to submit it as an idea here: https://datascix.uservoice.com/forums/387207-general/filters/top